# Using flask to run a python script

Tags: python, flask

I have a script called output.py

This script takes in 2 inputs, fileA and file B.
I can run it on my terminal by using the command output.py -fileA -fileB. The script will create a new JSON file and save it to the directory.

I want to run this script using Flask. I've defined a bare bones App here but I'm not sure how I'd run this using Flask

```
from flask import Flask
import output 
import scripting
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def script():
    return output 
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Can someone help me out here, thanks!

Comment: Can you add some more information about the input for the script? Is the input coming from your Flask app? What do you want to return from your Flask endpoint?

Comment: I have an angular front end, upon clicking the download buttons two files will be downloaded. Now an another friend of mine is working on writing POST requests to send the files to this Flask App. I would like to return the new JSON object back to my angular front end

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are new to Flask. Get some basic tutorials (there are many on the web).

There are a couple of options:

1. Send contents of file A and File b as json payload. Pull the A and B content off the json body and do the processing you need to and return the body.
2. Send the contents of the file as multipart/form-data (you can send multiple files).

Note: This is not working code - just for illustration.

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

def build_response(status=False, error="", data={}, total=0, headers=[], contentType="application/json", expose_headers=["X-Total-Count"], retcode=400, additional_data=None):
    resp = {"success": status, "error": error, "data": data}
    resp = make_response(json.dumps(resp))
    for item in headers:
        resp.headers[item] = headers[item]

    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = contentType
    resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', ','.join(expose_headers))
    resp.status_code = retcode
    return resp


@app.route('/run-script', methods=['POST'])
def run_script():
    # check if the post request has the file part
    try: 
        # Note: THis code is just to illustrate  the concept.
        # Option-1 (content type must be application/json)
        json_dict = request.get_json()
        fileA = json_dict["fileA"]
        fileB = json_dict["fileB"]
 
        # Option-2 (Note: fileA/fileB are objects, put a pdb and check it out)
        fileA = request.files['fileA']
        fileB = request.files['fileA']


        resp = process(fileA, fileB)
        return build_response(status=True, data=resp, retcode=200)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = f"Error - {str(ec)}"
        return build_response(status=False, error=msg, retcode=400)
```